# Capture the record visitor details on lightning record page it is org default

Tags: salesforce-lightning, lwc, lightning

I have one lightning record page which is org default. I want to show on record level current user name and no. of times he visited page. I wanted to achieve this using lightning web component. can you help me . I am new to LWC.

I tried this https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000393631&type=1 but I want to show on record level along with count (no. of time he visited on page) and username.